# AWS attach-policy-role returns 400 because of invalid-arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I was trying to get my code onto AWS with CodeDeploy. To do this I had to create a role, which I am currently stuck on. I set up the policy like so:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

and saved the file as `service-role.json`. I then used the command:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name MyServiceRole --assume-role-policy-document file://service-role.json
```

which I got to run ... eventually. That returned some JSON:

```
{                                                                               
    "Role": {                                                                   
        "Path": "/",                                                            
        "RoleName": "MyServiceRole",                                
        "RoleId": "SOMESTRINGOFRANDOMALPHANUMERICS",                                      
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::1123445569:role/MyServiceRole",      
        "CreateDate": "2018-08-31T03:18:24Z",                                   
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {                                           
            "Version": "2012-10-17",                                            
            "Statement": [                                                      
                {                                                               
                    "Sid": "",                                                  
                    "Effect": "Allow",                                          
                    "Principal": {                                              
                        "Service": [                                            
                            "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"                          
                        ]                                                       
                    },                                                          
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"                                  
                }                                                               
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This all looked correct, so I tried to run:

```
aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name MyServiceRole --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::1123445569:role/MyServiceRole
```

and ... I got the response

```
An error occurred (InvalidInput) when calling the AttachRolePolicy operation: ARN arn:aws:iam::1123445569:role/MyServiceRole is not valid.
```

I've combed the internet looking for a solution to this as it appears I've done exactly what [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html#getting-started-create-service-role-cli) instructed me to but I'm still getting no results. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attaching assume role policy you have created (and was already attached to the **MyServiceRole** while creation), attach one of the AWS privileges roles that are described in the [mentioned tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html#getting-started-create-service-role-cli) (step 3), so:

```
aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name MyServiceRole --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRole
```

or

```
aws iam attach-role-policy --role-name MyServiceRole --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSCodeDeployRoleForLambda
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I really overthought it what they wanted :)